# Display media embed in CKEditor 5

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor

I use CKEditor 5 in React js. There is a feature to insert a media link. It works fine and it saves DB in correctly. but that media embed doesn't display when data retrieve. When inserting URL for media some error messages display in the console log. They are

1. **Feature Policy: Skipping unsupported feature name “autoplay”**
2. **Feature Policy: Skipping unsupported feature name “encrypted-media”.**
3. **.Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at
   https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/id. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).**
4. **The resource at “” was blocked because content blocking is enabled.**
   **2. Some cookies are misusing the recommended “SameSite“ attribute**